# Equality in the Schwarz-Pick theorem implies function is a linear fractional?

Tags: complex-analysis

Part of the Schwarz-Pick Theorem states that for an analytic automorphism of the unit disk, then
$$
\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}.
$$
In the Wikipedia article of the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem), it is mentioned that if equality holds, then $f$ is a Mobius transformation on the unit disk without proof.

Is there a proof of this detail? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$f$ is assumed to be a holomorphic function that maps the disk to itself, not necessarily an automorphism. Let $a$ be in the unit disk, and let $b=f(a)$.  Let $\phi_a(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\overline az}$ be the holomorphic automorphism of the disk that swaps $a$ and $0$, and similarly $\phi_b(z)=\frac{b-z}{1-\overline b z}$.  If $g = \phi_b\circ f\circ \phi_a$, then $g$ is a holomorphic function that maps the disk to itself, and $g(0)=0$, so by Schwarz (or Cauchy's estimate) $|g'(0)|\leq 1$.  Since $\phi_a'(0)=|a|^2-1$ and $\phi_b'(b)=\frac{1}{|b|^2-1}$, this yields by the chain rule $$\frac{1}{1-|b|^2}|f'(a)|(1-|a|^2)\leq 1,$$ or $$\frac{|f'(a)|}{1-|b|^2}\leq \frac{1}{1-|a|^2}.$$  Since $a$ was arbitrary and $b=f(a)$, this means that $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$$ for all $z$ in the disk.  If for some $a$ the inequality had been equality, then by Schwarz we would have $g(z)=cz$ for some $c$ with $|c|=1$.  This means that $f=\phi_b\circ g\circ \phi_a$ is a composition of three Möbius transformations and automorphisms of the unit disk, hence is one itself.

Comment: Yes, it implies that $|g'(0)|=1$.  The inequality is a rearrangment of (and equivalent to) $|g'(0)|\leq 1$.